# JavaScript ES6 Module OnLoad handler implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, node-modules

I have a NodeJS server application which is split to lost of ES6 modules. I am trying to create a kind of "load module handler", a function in the main module, which other modules would require to register a callback, which will be executed after the main module is fully initialized. I am using Babel (with `babel-preset-es2015`) to transpile ES6 modules into executable JavaScript.

To demonstrate the issue here in short, I've created 2 sample files.

File `index.js` (application entry, main module):

```
import * as js2 from "./js2.js";

let toCall = [], // this array handles callbacks from other modules
    initialized = false; // flag

export function onInit (cb) { // registers cb to execute after this module is initialized
    if (initialized) {
        cb();
        return;
    }
    toCall.push(cb);
}

function done () { // initialization is done - execute all registered callbacks
    toCall.forEach(f => f());
}

// some important stuff here
// callback(() => {
        initialized = true;
        done();
// });
```

And the other module `js2.js`:

```
import { onInit } from "./index";

onInit(() => {
    console.log("Now I can use initialized application!");
});
```

All seems to be OK to me, but unfortunately this doesn't work throwing the next error in the first file:

```
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Thing is, there is no `toCall` variable at this point, but why? Variable `toCall` is declared *before* `onInit` function, it must be ready to use in `onInit`, mustn't it? How to solve this and is my way rational enough to implement something called "module initialization callbacks"? Are there any other solutions for this?

Thank you for any help and advice.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue in a babel/React app. A module is loaded before one of its imports causing an `undefined` exception. :(

Comment: So the solution to my issue is not to have top level module code running, only in the root entry point JS file. I was using Babel with CommonJS which handles module loading based on import dependencies, but the browser still has to run the code synchronously which can result in loading order issues. I think one solution to your problem is to put module code in an IIFE which will run after all dependencies are satisfied. I hope this comment is relevant.

Comment: Brenden, thanks for your hints. However, I started use the tactic you've mentioned as I didn't find the answer for my question yet. Of course, having the answer will allow to make the project architecture a lot more beautiful.
May be, it's a Babel issue. Looking through the generated ES5 code, the solution I can guess is just to place `require(...)`s *after* all the require-independent variable declarations.
Look to my answer here, I've found a right way.

Comment: I don't see the point of defining such callbacks. All initialization can be done without circular dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a beautiful implementation for this.

It is needed to separate "onload handler" implementation to individual module. As a result of this example, there will be three files:

`index.js`:

```
import * as js2 from "./js2.js";
import { initDone } from "./init.js";

// some important stuff here
// callback(() => {
    console.log(`Main module is initialized!`);
    initDone();
// });
```

`js2.js`:

```
import { onInit } from "./init.js";

onInit(() => {
    console.log("Module js2.js is initialized!");
});
```

`init.js`:

```
let toCall = [], // this array has to handle functions from other modules
    initialized = false; // init flag

export function onInit (cb) {
    if (initialized) {
        cb();
        return;
    }
    toCall.push(cb);
}

export function initDone () {
    initialized = true;
    toCall.forEach(f => f());
}
```

And the result:

```
Main module is initialized!
Module js2.js is initialized!
```